# Convert Linq to regular function

Tags: c#, linq

i have this linq method how get all machine network card properties and i don't want to use linq, can i have some help to convert it and not using Linq ?

```
public NetworkAdapter[] GetAll()
{
    return (from adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            from uniCast in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
            where !System.Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6
            let lastGatewayAddress = adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.LastOrDefault()
            select new NetworkAdapter()
            {
                string Name = adapter.Name,
                string ID = adapter.Id,
                string Description = adapter.Description,
                string IPAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString(),
                string NetworkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString(),
                string Speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0"),
                string MacAddress = getMacAddress(adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()),
                string gatewayIpAddress = string.Join(" ", adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(a => a.Address))
            }).ToArray();
}
```

this is what i have try;

```
public void get()
{
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        Description = adapter.Description;
        Name = adapter.Name;
        MacAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();

        IPInterfaceProperties ips = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection uniCast = ips.UnicastAddresses;

        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ipInfo in uniCast)
        {
            if (ipInfo.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you **not** want to use Linq, if it makes your code simpler?

Comment: i took this code from here and only want to learn how to convert it and not using  Linq

Comment: @Shaul - Because sometimes it doesn't. Linq is great, but if you're not used to it, it takes some time to understand, what's happening. Also you can't put breakpoints "inside" Linq statements. (Or can you?)

Comment: @Corak - Right, I get it: sometimes I also prefer to rub two sticks together; I just can't get the hang of those "match" doodads...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I don't understand why, here goes.

With a little help from my friend ReSharper (and my input because ReSharper couldn't do it all):

```
public NetworkAdapter[] GetAll()
    {
        List<NetworkAdapter> list = new List<NetworkAdapter>();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uniCast in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (!System.Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                {
                    StringBuilder gatewayIPAddresses = new StringBuilder();
                    string gatewayIPAddressesDisplay = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var address in adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
                    {
                        gatewayIPAddresses.Append(address.Address);
                        gatewayIPAddresses.Append(" ");
                    }

                    if (gatewayIPAddresses.Length > 0)
                    {
                        gatewayIPAddressesDisplay = gatewayIPAddresses.ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
                    }

                    list.Add(new NetworkAdapter()
                        {
                            Name = adapter.Name,
                            ID = adapter.Id,
                            Description = adapter.Description,
                            IPAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString(),
                            NetworkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString(),
                            Speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0"),
                            MacAddress = getMacAddress(adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()),
                            gatewayIpAddress = gatewayIPAddressesDisplay
                        });
                }
            }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You are still using Linq, e.g. `GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(a => a.Address)`

Comment: Actually, it would be closer to reality if, instead of building a list, you have an iterator method (i.e. using `yield return`) and then call `ToArray` on its result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Check my update, it seems even ReSharper couldn't do it on it's own ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's not Linq, that's a lambda function and a regular method.

Comment: @JonGrant: So is [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) not located in the `System.Linq` namespace?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess I understood the question as not wanting to use the Linq syntax (from where select etc), rather than any specific namespace.

Comment: @Shaul Hahaha it really does! You know I recently got a free license for ReSharper 7 because I reported an exploit in the license checking process which meant you could run the trial for free forever!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public NetworkAdapter[] GetAll()
        {
            var networkAdapters = new List<NetworkAdapter>();

            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uniCast in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (!System.Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) &&
                        uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                    {
                        GatewayIPAddressInformation lastGatewayAddress = adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.LastOrDefault();

                        networkAdapters.Add(new NetworkAdapter()
                                                {
                                                    Name = adapter.Name,
                                                    ID = adapter.Id,
                                                    Description = adapter.Description,
                                                    IPAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString(),
                                                    NetworkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString(),
                                                    Speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0"),
                                                    MacAddress = getMacAddress(adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()),
                                                    gatewayIpAddress = string.Join(" ", adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(a => a.Address))
                                                });
                    }
                }
            }

            return networkAdapters.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: You are still using Linq, e.g. `GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(a => a.Address)`